# Javascript External Object Global?

Tags: javascript, object, scope

I'm messing around with objects and methods, and I have this really simple example that I use to test with:

```js
var shout = {
  hello: function(variable){
    console.log("Hello " + variable);
  }
};

shout.hello("World");
```

And this works fine. However, if I place the object `shout` in an external file, and then run `shout.hello("world");` I get nothing:

```js
//external file: test.js
var shout = {
  hello: function(variable){
    console.log("Hello " + variable);
  }
};
```

```html
<!-- my html document -->
<script src="test.js">
shout.hello("World");
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> `script` elements with an `src` attribute specified should not have a script embedded within its tags.

You need two separate `script` tags, one to import your external script, and another to call the function, for example:

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
<script>
shout.hello("World");
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need two separate `script` tags, the content of a tag with [`src` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#Attributes) is ignored.

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
<script>
    shout.hello("World");
</script>
```

Comment: I'm gonna accept this answer cause it was first, and it works.
Can you explain the reason for this, though? EDIT: Gotcha! I did not know this :)